# Error with an Erase function for a Binary Tree? (C++)

Tags: c++, crash, binary-tree, erase

So I'm working on an erase function for a binary tree where a key is given and the root is given as parameters.
There's the definition of the structure for the tree:

```
struct BST_Node {
 string key;
 string things;   //not relevant to this function
 BST_Node * left, * right;
};
     typedef BST_Node * BST;
```

However, for some reason, my first case keeps crashing when I try running it.

```
void BST_delete(string key, BST & tree) {

//before is just the predecessor 
BST_Node* before = NULL;
BST_Node* current = tree;

while(current!= NULL){
    if(current->key == key)
    {
        break;
    }
    else{
        before = current;   //the node before current
        if( key < current->key)
        {
            current = current->right;
        }
        else{
            current = current->left;
        }
        }
}


//FIRST CASE - has no children, so just deleting the Node.
          //then assigning the "before" node to point to NULL since it was originally       pointing to the node that was just deleted. 
 (need to check if the left or right of "before" pointed to "current"

if(current -> left == NULL && current->right==NULL)
{
    if(before->right == current)
    {
        before->right == NULL;
    }
    else if(before->left == current)
    {
        before->left == NULL;
    }

    delete current;
}
```

Comment: what is your function BST_delete supposed to do exactly? And what error do you get?

Comment: @ChrisMaes you're given a Node (target node) that you needto delete, and the key that refers to that node is also given. It just crashes when I run it. It does compile though.

Answer (score 0):

you access `current -> left` without checking whether `current == NULL`: change to:

```
if(current && current->left == NULL && current->right==NULL)
```

EDIT: probably you want to change `if( key < current->key)` to

```
if( key > current->key)
```

Comment: ahh you're right. I put an assert(current!=NULL) and i switched the sign to >, i don't know how i mixed that up.  However, I still seem to not have it working properly. The logic makes sense right?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have fixed up the tests that Chris Maes suggested, you also need to change

```
before->right == NULL;
```

There should only be one = in an assignment. Change it to

```
before->right = NULL;
```